Index Composite Firestore is not recognize
On my angular app, I want to use this firestore query
return from(this.collection.ref.where('nom', '>=', filtre)
      .where('nom', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
      .where('prenom', '>=', filtre)
      .where('prenom', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
      .where('email', '>=', filtre)
      .where('email', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
      .where('numero', '==', parseInt(filtre))
      .limit(10)
      .get()

I have create both composite index on firestore

One with each column once
One with each column twice as use in request (except numero)

Index are active. But when I call my request, i have an error :

ERROR FirebaseError: The query contains range and inequality filters on multiple fields, please refer to the documentation for index selection best practices: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/multiple-range-fields. The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/xxx/firestore/indexes?create_composite=xxxxx {code: 'failed-precondition', customData: undefined, name: 'FirebaseError', toString: ƒ, stack: 'FirebaseError: The query contains range and i…xxxxx', …}

Request has to search all document of my collection where my string text in parameters is part of one of these 4 columns (like)
I don't understand why ...
EDIT 1
After Frank van Puffelen respons, I saw that AngularFirestore is not compatible with and / or operator.
I have try with Firestore SDK but I have this message on the use of requeteXxx query on the or funtion in requeteCombinee
import { Timestamp, getFirestore , or, query, where, collection, getDocs, limit } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, DocumentReference } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

    const requeteNom = query(
  collection(this.db, 'mycollection*emphasized text*'),
  where('nom', '>=', filtre),
  where('nom', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
);
  
const requetePrenom = query(
  collection(this.db, 'mycollection'),
  where('prenom', '>=', filtre),
  where('prenom', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
);
  
const requeteEmail = query(
  collection(this.db, 'mycollection'),
  where('email', '>=', filtre),
  where('email', '<=', filtre + '\uf8ff')
);
  
const requeteNumero = query(
  collection(this.db, 'mycollection'),
  where('numero', '==', parseInt(filtre))
);
  
const requeteCombinee = query(
  collection(this.db, 'mycollection'),
  or(requeteNom, requetePrenom, requeteEmail, requeteNumero),
  limit(10)
);
  
return from(getDocs(requeteCombinee)).pipe(
  map(snapshot => snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data() as MyResult))
);

The error
Argument of type 'Query<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFilterConstraint'.
      Type 'Query<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 'QueryFieldFilterConstraint'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type '"query" | "collection"' is not assignable to type '"where"'.
            Type '"query"' is not assignable to type '"where"'.ts(2345)


For information, without all where criteria, request is OK (and too with only one column selection)

If you click the link after "create it here", you should be taken to Firestore console with all fields to create the required index prepopulated.

OK thanks, it's seem that order for column in index is important !
I have created the index and no error but, There are no results even though I should have some. Is this query, which should return all records whose text is in the nom, prenom email OR numero field, correct? (AND or OR management)
Example :  nom or prenom or mail or numero should contain bro ? or 123 ?

Yup, orderBy clauses also affect the result - so they must be in the index too. I only see AND conditions in your query (the default). If you want OR, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries

This is not implement in AngularFirestore, when I try with firestore SDK directly, I can't find the solution  (see Edit 1)

@Broshet As per the example in this document or operator accepts field constraints (such as where). Use Firestore's in operator to determine whether a certain field in your documents has one or more values. Also check if your using latest versions of Firestore and Angularfire .

At beginning of the project I was on Angular 17. Or conditions in Firestore are implemented with Angular 18 .
I have upgrade my project at Angular 18 and "And / or" command are OK
